# Send keys to FreeBSD in VirtualBox

Tags: c#, virtualbox, freebsd, sendkeys, sendinput

I'm trying to make a small application in C# which sending keys to FreeBSD in VirtualBox, but it doesn't work. I tried the SendKeys and the InputSimulator but nothing happend. It works properly in notepad, but not in the VirtualBox. Have anyone got idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that VirtualBox is filtering the keys, since it's stateful as to whether or not the keyboard and mouse are bound to the VM or to the host and VBox's UI.

You might be able to hack this by generating a mouse click event in the middle of the console display to make sure VBox has bound the keyboard to the VM, and then start the send keys.

Also, Vbox has a scripting system. If you can't get this to work, maybe you could use that to get done what you need.